# How use react-redux connect with mapStateToProps,MapDispatchToProps and redux-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to use in my container "LoginPage" (smart-component) redirect after login.
Something like this:

```
handleSubmit(username, pass, nextPath) {
    function redirect() {
        this.props.pushState(null, nextPath);
    }
    this.props.login(username, pass, redirect); //action from LoginAcitons
  }
```

username and pass arrived from dumb-component.

Smart component connect

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.app.user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(LoginActions, dispatch)
}
```

How I can add pushState from redux-router ? Or I'm on wrong way?

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {pushState})(LoginPage); //works, but haven't actions

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage); //works, but haven't pushState

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, {pushState})(LoginPage); //Uncaught TypeError: finalMergeProps is not a function
```

Comment: I am stuck in a similar problem. What are `LoginActions` here?

Comment: why does this need to be done in the component itself? Just curious.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.app.user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(LoginActions, dispatch),
    routerActions: bindActionCreators({pushState}, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: The key thing in here was realizing that in mapStateToProps, "state" isn't just the local state of the object, but the single state of the redux application. I think the tendency is to think you can just use return { user: state.user } because most likely { user: '' } is what you've got locally to that component's actions, reducers, etc.

Comment: @netpoetica Thank you! This is underemphasized in the redux documentation, I was confused about the same thing. Granted, I probably skimmed it too fast XD

Answer (score 1):

Simple skeleton :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore,applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import View from './view';
import {playListReducer, artistReducers} from './reducers'


/*create rootReducer*/


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  playlist: playListReducer,
  artist: artistReducers
})

/* create store */
let store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(logger ,thunk));


/*  connect view and store   */
const App = connect(
  state => ({
    //same key as combineReducers
    playlist:state.playlist,
    artist:state.artist
  }),
  dispatch => ({

    })
  )(View);



ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>  ,
  document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```