# Get redux state on window.scroll

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to implement pagination. So when a user scrolls down to the bottom I want to make an api call.  I see through window.scroll I can find position of scroll and can achieve that. However I want to access redux state to get certian data. Since this event is not bind by any component I won't be able to pass down data. What would be the correct approach in this scenario?
If I want to access redux store through a simple function How can I do that? And on scroll how do I make sure that only request goes through?

Comment: I haven't used it, but perhaps [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) can help you.

Comment: @JoPeyper Thanks. I found something https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint looks interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**connect**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34450688/2733506) your component that does the scroll. or you can pass props to the component that have the store information. Those are the two recommended ways to reach your store. That being said you can also look at the context

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  someMethod() {
    doSomethingWith(this.context.store);
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Note: Context is opt-in; you have to specify `contextTypes` on the component to get it.

Read up on [React's Context doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) It may not be a complete solution since it could be deprecated in a future version

---

Edit:

Per the comments with the clarity you provided you can just do this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM = from 'react-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';

const defaultOffset = 300;

var topOfElement = function(element) {
    if (!element) {
        return 0;
    }
    return element.offsetTop + topOfElement(element.offsetParent);
};

class InfiniteScroll extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.listener = _.throttle(this.scrollListener, 200).bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.attachScrollListener();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.detachScrollListener();
    }

    scrollListener () {
        var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        var offset = this.props.offset || defaultOffset;
        var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
        if (topOfElement(el) + el.offsetHeight - scrollTop - window.innerHeight < offset) {
            this.props.somethingHere;
        }
    }

    attachScrollListener() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listener);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.listener);
        this.listener();
    }

    detachScrollListener() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listener);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.listener);
    }

    render() {
        return (...)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InfiniteScroll);
```

I added lodash to the import here so you can throttle the scroll listener function. you only want to call the handler function so many times a second or it can start lagging the page (depending on how heavy the listener function is)

Comment: You can connect your component that does the scroll ?  That component would be what? , since I want to call window.scroll .  I don't want a fixed container for scrolling. I want something like facebook does when you scroll down get the new data

Comment: @scripter I am assuming you are going to make an `InfiniteScroll` component that handles the `window.scroll` listener and everything so you can use that code in more than one place. I was saying that component (or if you don't make an infinite scroll component whatever component that should be requesting more data) could be connected.

Comment: You shouldn't use the redux store directly via store if it's not necessary. In this case you should us the official module to connect Components and the redux store: `react-redux`;

Comment: @floriangosse as I said in my answer. You can connect the component or pass props as those are the two **recommended** ways. However the context.store is currently a supported method and is a way to do it. since the OP asked for a way to do it without the first two recommended options the third (if not as optimal) is a way to do it :)

Comment: @floriangosse is right. you should not use context directly unless you absolutely have to **and know what you are doing**. [Its an experimental api](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context) so use with caution even if you do know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks guys. Usually I connect all my components using connect(). I will take a look at both ways .

Comment: @scripter you said --- * If I want to access redux store through a simple function How can I do that? * --- I assumed that meant that you weren't able to connect this component for some reason. Is that not the case? It would definitely be better to connect it if you have that as an option

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes I need to figure out how to trigger scroll handler. If it's triggering from a component, then using connect() to pass down data, won't be an issue but when I want to use global window.scroll then connecting the function to store is confusing for me.

Comment: @scripter oh thats easy let me update my answer with an example

Comment: @JohnRuddell Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access your application state in components is the usage of `react-redux` and selectors functions.

`react-redux` provides a function which is called `connect`. You should use this function to define which values from our state you want to map to the props of the component so these will be available.

The function you need for this mapping is called `mapStateToProps`which returns an object with the values which should be passed to the component.

Also you can be define redux actions which should be made available in the component (e.g. for trigger the load of the next page). The function is called `mapDispatchToProps`.

Here an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getUsersPage } from './selectors';
import { loadUsersPage } from './actions';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    handleScroll () {
        this.props.loadUsersPage({ page: lastPage + 1 });
    }

    render () {
        const users = this.props.users;

       // ...
    }
}

const mapStateToThis = (state) => {
    return {
        users: getUsers(state)
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadUsersPage: (payload) => {
            dispatch (loadUsersPage(payload));
        }
    }
};

export default connect()(MyComponent);
```